# How to skip lines in php

Tags: php

I'm struggling in finding a way to correctly do this logic.

```
If (this thing is null)
   Skip it
Else 
   Don't skip it
```

I tried with if/else and while loops but each one will crash the program. I test something like this:

```
(inside a foreach)
if($value->getThing() == NULL) {
   //HOW TO SKIP???
      //I try to 'set' this thing
    $value->setThing(0); //BUT IT Doesn't work because it's an associated object...
} else {
   $value->getThing();
}
```

And tried this:

```
(inside foreach)
while ($value->getThing() != NULL) {
    $value->getThing();
    //Do Calculation...
}
```

Both just crash when it gets to the thing thats null. I know why but I can't figure out how to skip the null thing.

and if you can't tell, I'm a newbie. But I'm learning.

EDIT: The thing is null in the db.

Comment: try single quotes in NULL, like this - if($value->getThing() == 'NULL')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

```
foreach($values as $value){
   if(!is_null($value->getThing())){
    #do calculation
  }
}
```

Comment: You responded first so I will accept your answer. I still have errors but not exactly related to this anymore. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

For "skipping" an entry you can use "continue".

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if($value['foo'] == null){
        continue;
    }
    //Do the calculation
}
```

..or perhaps:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if(is_null($value['foo'])){
        //Null value treatment
        continue;
    }
    //Do the calculation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually looking for is the `NOT IS` Operator as I like to call it.

```
foreach ($things as $thing) {
    if (!is_null($thing)) {
        // Do the stuff that you wanna do
    }
}
```

The above dummy code teaches that you do not have to use an `else`. It also shows the `is_null()` function which checks if something is actually `NULL`. Furthermore it shows the `!` operator that can also be translated to `NOT IS`.

What `!is_null()` actually says is: "If the return value of this function, variable and so on is not `NULL`..."

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$names = file('name.txt');

// To check the number of lines 

echo count($names).'<br>';

foreach($names as $name) {
   echo $name.'<br>';
}
```